# Java8 : stream and map transformations

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I want to turn a `List` into something different.

I have a POJO class like this (I removed here getters/setters) :

```
public class Person {
   private String personId;
   private String registrationId;
}
```

A `Person` (personId) can have many registrationId, so different `Person` instances may refer the same real person (but have different registrationId).

I have a `List<Person> persons` as follows with 3 elements :

```
persons = [{"person1", "regis1"}, {"person1", "regis2"}, {"person2", "regis1"}];
```

I would like something like this (so that each key refers to a person and for each person I got the list of registrationId) :

```
Map<String, List<String>> personsMap = [ "person1" : {"regis1", "regis2"}, "person2" : {"regis2"}]
```

I know I can do something like this :

```
Map<String, List<Person>> map = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getPersonId));
```

But I got a `Map<String,List<Person>>` and I would like a `Map<String,List<String>>`

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Use `Collectors.mapping` to map the `Person` instances to the corresponding registrationId `String`s:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = 
    persons.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getPersonId,
                                          Collectors.mapping(Person::getRegistrationId,
                                                             Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: ‍ ‍‍‍‍`Collectors.toMap()` or `Collectors.toList()` ?

Comment: @HadiJ oops, I mis-typed. Thanks!

Comment: removing the instances of the word "Collectors" by adding a static import will make this answer readable as an english statement

Answer (score 0):

And also you can use `toMap` with merge function

```
Map<String,List<String>> map= persons
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getPersonId,
                        value->new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Person::getRegistrationId)),
                        (l1,l2)->{l1.addAll(l2);return l1;}));
```

as @Holger commented not to need create a temporary array.

```
Map<String,List<String>> map= persons
  .stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getPersonId,
                    value->new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(Person::getRegistrationId)),
                    (l1,l2)->{l1.addAll(l2);return l1;}));
```